# Calculate time difference and compared it into Google Apps script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let me explain the context:

Pallets travel a path and enter at a time and date "T", they may exit at a "random" time.

By random, I mean that it is possible that a pallet can very well arrive on August 30th in the gallery and leave on August 31st.

Here is an extract of the current results on a Google Sheets sheet. (20k lines).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AboVGsyN4vyApwsnIt8KfWv0bWf0GnZCNeF5eBEI0Js/edit?usp=sharing

Sorting first by pallet number.

I would like to go through all the rows, check that the row+1 has the same pallet number and the same "Type".
If this is the case, I would like to calculate the time difference between these two lines. For example, if the pallet enters at 7h58m00s in the morning, and leaves the next day at 7h59m00s, I would like to obtain a value (here 24:01:00).
This difference would then be checked if it exceeds 00:00:30 (s).

Let's imagine a first pallet comes in at 8h20m26s, the second at 8h20m45s, the second would be deleted.

I had tried at first by browsing a 2D list containing the values of the sheet and by applying my conditions, but unfortunately it was complicated to compare hours (which are dates in hours format) with a duration.

Because of this, I could not get an efficient script, by going through various means it took so much time that the script stopped.

On excel, my macro was working as :

```
    lig = 2
   nb_col = (last column of data in the sheet)
   nb_lig = (last row of data in the sheet).
loop:
    If Cells(lig, 1).Text = Cells(lig + 1, 1).Text And _
    Cells(lig, 4).Value = Cells(lig + 1, 4).Value Then
        diff= Cells(lig + 1, 2).Value - Cells(lig, 2).Value
        diff= diff+ Cells(lig + 1, 3).Value - Cells(lig, 3).Value
        If diff< "00:00:30" Then
            Rows(lig + 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            nb_lig = nb_lig - 1
            GoTo loop
        End If
    End If
    If Cells(lig, 4).Value = "E" Then
        If Cells(lig + 1, 4).Value = "S" Then
            If Cells(lig, 1).Text = Cells(lig + 1, 1).Text Then
                Cells(lig, nb_col - 2).Value = Cells(lig + 1, 5).Value
                Cells(lig, nb_col - 1).Value = Cells(lig + 1, 3).Value
                Cells(lig + 1, nb_col - 2).value = Cells(lig, 5).value
                Cells(lig + 1, nb_col - 1).value = Cells(lig, 3).value
                diff= Cells(lig + 1, 2).value - Cells(lig, 2).value
                diff= diff+ Cells(lig + 1, 3).Value - Cells(lig, 3).Value
                Cells(lig + 1, nb_col).Value = diff
            End If
        End If
    End If
    lig = lig + 1
    If Cells(lig, 1).Text <> "" Then GoTo loop
```

So, I think on Google Apps Script, I should write a column formula that would do this job but I can't really find it, especially since the algorithm I had done before had way too long of an execution time and didn't lead to the results I wanted.

If someone could at least give me some guidance on how to solve this, it would really be a kind gesture.

Comment: Do you have a code you're working on in Apps Script?

Comment: I had but it didn't work as I expected so I just deleted it

Comment: I'm working on actually so I can't make it faster. I gave precisely what I've done in Excel, just learning Google Apps Script

Answer (score 0):

First step is to make a date object - containing date and time. Combine Column B and C to make a new Date(). Then you can compare the date.getTime() value with the next row. If it is same, mark a cell in a particular column with a color or write a value in a free column in the right side.

If the table is not sorted, you have to run the loop as many times as there are unmarked rows. If the table is sorted, you can run it once only.

In the second step, start from the bottom and delete the colored cells or marked cells travelling upwards.

If you delete the unwanted row in the first step, the row reference will change and the loop will fail.